# Disable redirect for iframe using javascript

Tags: javascript, .htaccess

I have htacess code that redirects

```
http://website.com:352/pictures/1 to another page.
```

I would like to prevent this redirect if the request is in iframe src. Is this possible?

```
<iframe src="http://website.com:352/pictures/1" style="border: none; width:100%; height:1100px;"></iframe>
```

Comment: The server doesn't care if its an iframe or not, htaccess is sending it on its way. If you find a solution later down the line while being able to keep the code in the htaccess, please answer your own question as this sounds like a neat one

Comment: Somewhat relevant to your need, but as source says, not reliable -> http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4500939/htaccess-redirect-unless-in-iframe

Comment: I just read what you linked for referer. How could it be applied in this case?

Comment: The Referrer is an absolutely unreliable variable. Forget that it exists.

Comment: This would be easiest to solve, if you appended a query string to your iframe src, such as `http://website.com:352/pictures/1?noredirect`, and then checked for the existence of that value in the query string before doing the rewriting, via a `RewriteCond` before your RewriteRule.

Comment: Any way how this could be done, appending the query string that is.

Answer (score 0):

You can do that by adding a request header to the request and then check in your htaccess file for that header and make the redirect if the header does not exist.

However, to add a request header to the iframe, you need to make a workaround by creating AJAX request that and appending the results to the iframe
You can check this answer that explains how to do that: [How to set custom http headers when changing iframe src?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17694807/how-to-set-custom-http-headers-when-changing-iframe-src/17695034#17695034)